# loop through hash_map using iterator in multithreaded program

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, iterator, hashmap

Linux GCC:

I have a hash_map H, and a function F that using an iterator to loop through H, the problem is that function F can be executed in multithreaded mode. I don't know why it's working not stable, it seems that iterator is not safe in multi-threaded program. Any idea?

```
MY_HASH::iterator endIter = m_hash.end();
    for ( hm_Iter = m_hash.begin( ); hm_Iter != endIter; hm_Iter++)
    {
        pList->pData[i].id = hm_Iter->second->id ;
        pList->pData[i].data = hm_Iter->second->data ;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: `f()` itself isn't modifying the container, and will be safe to call from multiple threads as long as no other thread modifies the container, or the values you're reading from it, while `f()` is running. It's also possible that something else is interfering with pList, pList->pData etc... Also check that you've presized it correctly... perhaps use `at()` temporarily if it's a `vector` to get some runtime checks.

Comment: You can definitely have multiple threads do concurrent read-only iterations across a Standard or TR1 container.  If this is your own hash container, you'll have to check the code yourself.

Comment: Yes, this hash_map is not my self but it is not C++ Standard. In Windows it is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\hash_map

Comment: I don't think there's a "C++ Standard" `hash_map`. Maybe a GNU extension? Why not use `unordered_map`? Also, could you just say `pList->pData[i] = *hmIter->second`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_map_(C%2B%2B) says that unordered_map just similar to hash_map template that I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see that the hash iteration would be having problems, but I suspect assigning to `pList->pData[i]` is where your multi-threading issue exists.

Comment: Could be.  @longbkit: is pList a function parameter, distinct per caller?

Comment: @Tony Yes it is distinct per caller, it is allocated inside function f(). So it's hardly be problematic